# Update and track file with git

Tags: git, ubuntu

I get the following message in on the terminal when using "git status":

```
Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
```

For Testing purpose I added a file, change a line in the code and added the file again(for tracking) to update the local git repo.

Comment: You need to give more info than that... looks like you have changes lol.

Comment: its telling you the changes that are committed. is the file you changed showing up as green under that?

Comment: "I added a file, change a line in the file, and added the file again to update the git repo." I am not sure what you are trying to do... you added the file to update the git repo. but you don't want to upload it to github?

Comment: Or do people only use git with github and not to localy keep track ? Again i upload my files to my server after im done, so i don't need github to share my files in public.

Comment: Okay so I think there are some misunderstandings with what git is. Github is a place that allows you to store repositories. "git" does not necessarily refer to github. You can keep your changes locally. You are only putting them on github when you push your changes there. If you setup your repository to link to github, then when you push that is where it will go. Commits do not go to the server. They stay locally until you push. The push is what sends them to github.

Comment: Yes i know. But why doesn't it says : "Nothing to commit, working directory clean." As t did before.

Comment: Because as you just said you made a change. The moment you make a change it will show up there.

Comment: So my question is how can i update it. So that that message go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git is a pretty big system, with a lot to learn about it.  You'll need more than just a few questions and answers on StackOverflow.

It will help if you know what version control systems (VCSes) are about.  See, for instance, [the introductory section of the free on-line Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control), or [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control), for a brief introduction to version control systems.  Git in particular is a *distributed* VCS, which makes it more useful, but also a great deal more complicated than most centralized VCSes.

In this particular case, while you've added some file, you have not yet *committed* that file, and the file's state, compared to the previous commit—if there is a previous commit at all<sup>1</sup>—is "new".  So `git status` is telling you that if you don't want this file to appear in the next commit, you can remove it from the *staging area* using `git rm --cached`.

The *staging area*, which has two more names—Git also calls it the *index* and the *cache*, for reasons having to do with the way it operates—is perhaps best thought of as being the place where you build up the next commit you will make.  It starts out matching the current commit.  The current commit is the *first* copy; the index contains a *second* copy of each file.  You can `git add` files to copy them from your work-tree—a *third* copy of each file—into the staging area.  If the file is new, this means the file now has two copies instead of three: the work-tree version, and the index version.

A *commit* takes everything that is in the index / staging-area right now and turns it into a permanent<sup>2</sup> and read-only snapshot.  Once committed, all the files that were in the index are now stored forever (except for footnote 2), frozen in time in the form they had at the moment you ran `git commit`.  Making a commit assigns the commit a unique ID.  This ID appears to be entirely random, and is a big ugly number that no human would want to remember

Each commit that you make also remembers its *parent* commit—the ID of the commit that *was* the current commit, up until the point you made the new commit, which immediately became the current commit.  Git can, given the *last* commit you made, use this parent ID to string together all the commits.  This is your history, stored permanently (mostly—footnote 2 strikes again) in your Git repository.  Everything in history is completely read-only, so you can always get it back exactly.

Git uses *branch names* like `master` to remember the big ugly hash ID of the *last* commit.  These names' stored IDs change as you make new commits: they always identify the *last* commit, because Git will—*must*—work backwards from last commit, to its parent, and then to the grand-parent, and so on.

The fact that history is (commits are) read-only is why the index / staging-area exists.  Files stored inside Git have a special, compressed, and read-only format.  Files in your work-tree have their ordinary read/write format.  Files in the index sit halfway between the two: they're in special format, but you can overwrite them.  That's what `git add` does: it overwrites the index copy.  If there was no index copy before, well, now there is.  If there was one before, well, now it's overwritten with the newer one.  But there's no snapshot yet: Git will make the snapshot later, when you run `git commit`.

---

<sup>1</sup>You've snipped enough of the `git status` output to make it difficult to tell if you have any existing commits (though older versions of Git don't make it as obvious as the latest versions).

<sup>2</sup>While commits are *mostly* permanent, it's possible (with some degree of difficulty) to get rid of them if they're useless.  Because Git is distributed, though, the moment you send the commit out to another copy of your repository, it becomes very difficult to delete it everywhere.  You can get rid of *your* copy, but you must get everyone else to get rid of *their* copies as well.  So you can think of commits as being *private* or unpublished, in which case they're easy-ish to delete, and *public* / published, in which case it's pretty hard.

Comment: I removed the .git and start over. So i do " git init" then "git add test.py". Now it says Initial commit with the above message again. How do i need to use this then ?

Comment: You still need to run `git commit`. That will make the first commit ever, in this otherwise new / empty repository. The thing that's special about the first commit is that it *doesn't* have a parent commit. Git's term for this is that the commit is a *root* commit (probably *the* root commit, you can make other root commits later but that's not a normal thing to do).

Comment: Doesn't it upload it to github then ? since i need to give user and name in the config file.

Comment: No! Committing is purely a local act. You use `git push` to have your Git contact another Git (such as one at GitHub) and *send* commits, and `git fetch` to have your Git contact another Git and *retrieve* commits. The user name and email address you configured go into what Git calls *commit metadata*; these are entirely separate from any user name and authentication you might use when talking to another Git on GitHub or wherever.

Comment: This is very different from *centralized* VCSes (CVCSes) like Subversion. In a CVCS, you cannot make your own commits: you must get the central server to make them, so you have to call up the central server and beg it to make a commit for you. That's what makes CVCSes so much simpler than DVCSes: a DVCS lets anyone make commits any time, and therefore needs ways to synchronize separate repositories.

Comment: CVCSes are much simpler to think about. There's only one version controller, located centrally. Everyone must plead with the central server to create commits or obtain files. The network must be up and running for you to get anything done, but there's only one guy with The Answers.

Comment: Thx. Just done it. I thought that it would be uploaded to github automaticly. Because they need my credentials.

Comment: I dont know the benefits of using git instead of just doing all this without git tho.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=benefits+of+using+a+version+control+system